# How to access shared data from a layout component in Vue/Inertiajs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have used [this instruction from inertiajs official website](https://inertiajs.com/shared-data) to share user auth data and it works fine for all pages except those who doesn't directly rendered by Inertia::render() method.

I need to access user authentication data from a layout component named <Master> but I can't!

here is my structure/heirarchy:

```
- Vue/
  - Pages/
    - Home/
      - Index.vue
    - Layouts/
      - Master.vue
      - Header.vue
      - Footer.vue
  - App.js
```

here is my <Master> component:

```
<template>
    <Head>
        <title>My Title</title>
    </Head>

    <Header :user="user"/>
    <slot/>
    <Footer/>
</template>

<script>
import Header from './Header';
import Footer from './Footer';
import {Head} from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
           user: this.auth.user,
        }
    },
    props:{
        auth: Object,
    },
    components: {
        Header,
        Footer,
        Head,
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$page` property or the `usePage()` hook.

```
<Header :user="$page.props.auth.user" />
```

```
const user = computed(() => usePage().props.value.auth.user)
```

If you scroll down the the link you have given you will know it.